# would definitely lose all after gambling for a long time?

Tags: probability, gambling

I have a mathematic question about gambling.

Given that Peter is gambling and

1. the winning probability $50\%$.
2. gain \$1 for winning, lose \$1 for loss
3. Initial capital: $\$A$
4. the game will end either capital reach $\$B$ or Peter lost all.
5. $n$ is the number of game playing.
6. $P(n)= \text{[probability of lost all]}$

Therefore,

$$ P(0)=1; \qquad P(B)=0 $$

and

$$
\begin{array}{rc}
& P(n) = 50\% \cdot P(n-1) + 50\% \cdot P (n+1) \\
\implies \quad & 2P(n) = P(n-1) + P(n+1) \\
\implies \quad & P(n)-P(n-1) = P(n+1) - P(n).
\end{array}
$$

$ ``\text{change of $P$''} = 1/B $

Therefore $P(A) = 1-A/B$.

If $B = \infty$, then $P(\infty) = 1$.

My question is, how about if the game winning probability is $60\%/40\%$ instead of $50\%/50\%$?
How should I calculate?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: It seems to me that you are considering the [gambler's ruin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin) problem. Your computation should also work for the unfair game you are considering, but now the recurrence relation you are going to solve will be a bit different. To give a hint, write the left-hand side of $$P(n)=(0.6)P(n+1) + (0/4)P(n-1)$$ as $(0.6)P(n) + (0.4)P(n)$ and try to reorganize the recurrence relation in a form similar to what you considered.

Comment: thank you so much for giving hint. However what should i do after the reorganizing the relation. I don't know what to do next :(

Comment: I guess you successfully arrived the relation $$ (0.6)(P(n+1) - P(n)) = (0.4)(P(n) - P(n-1)). $$ Rearranging, this gives $$ P(n+1) - P(n) = \frac{0.4}{0.6}(P(n) - P(n-1)), $$ which tells that $P(n) - P(n-1)$ itself is a geometric sequence. This will allow you to write $P(n)$ in terms of $P(0)$ and $P(1)$, and then the boundary conditions $P(0) = 1$ and $P(B) = 1$ will allow you to determine all the values of $P(n)$'s.